# Does gpresult work in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, group-policy

I'm trying to determine what GPO's are being applied to my Windows 7 machine in a Windows 2003 AD network.  However, whenever I bring up a command window and run the GPRESULT command, all I get are error messages.  Does gpresult work at all in Windows 7?

Comment: It should still work.  It is a valid command in Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the sense that I can start it just fine from the command line; nothing chrashes, no complaints. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. How are you running it, specifically?

Comment: I was running it from the command line in Windows 7.  It is on a 32-bit version of Windows 7, but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Rod correct, it has nothing to do with it. Usually, things tend to break in the 64 bit version, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Are you right-clicking and 
'Run as Administrator'

Works for me.

Else what error message do you get?